# Excel - Extract 2 characters after specific text in string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping someone can help me with an Excel formula to extract two characters after specific text in a string.

Specifically, the cell contains the following text

> *Every 2 Hours Power:1 Sail:0 SWC:3 BCR:0 CJC:0 CU:0 CSC:0*

Note that all cells are slightly different so I can't just use the text to columns delimiter. I need the formula to return the two characters after the specific text "Power:". From the example above, I want the cell to read "1" after the text "Power:".

I've tried various combinations of Right, Left, Len, Search, and am not having success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming that text is in A1: `=MID(A1,SEARCH("Power:",A1)+6,2)`

Comment: And add “*1” to @Rory answer so it becomes a number instead of text, could also use value()

Comment: Thank you Rory and Solar Mike! This worked to get the numbers when there was accidentally a space between the : and the #. I then also used Mayukh's solution below to extract when there was no space. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then one could use the following formula, which uses* `TEXTAFTER()` & `TEXTBEFORE()`

[image]

---

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"Power:")," ")
```

---

Or, Spill all at once,

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"Power:")," ")
```

---

Or, with `TEXTSPLIT()` & `TEXTAFTER()`

```
=--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1:A4,"Power:")," ")
```

---

Comment: Thank you Mayukh! This works perfectly. I used your first solution here. Happy New Years

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then go with `TEXTSPLIT()`.

```
=--TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1,"Power:"),," "),1)
```

For other versions, I would suggest to use `FILTERXML()`.

[image]